# Auto generation of Hibernate mapping files

Tags: hibernate

Just wanted to check how most people are generating their Hibernate mapping files and POJOs. I understand I can use Hibernate Tools, but what other options do I have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fewer and fewer people are generating mapping files - annotations are now widely adopted.

As for the generation - I've only heard of Hibernate Tools and the [hibernate maven plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/hibernate3-maven-plugin/)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote my own code. It was pretty simple. My database was DB2/400 (legacy with more than 200 fields on certain views) - there was no way I could hand write them. I investigated SYSCOLUMNS system table to check the column name, data type and generated domain classes with annotations. 60 lines of code saved me hours :)